# Counting thread post count on forums

Tags: php, mysql, query-optimization

I have a forum that has the thread title, post count, and other info.  I've managed to optimize the other queries/remove them completely, but the one that counts each thread's post count is slowing the main board page from loading.

i.e. `echo $boards->getPostCount($thread)`

inside `getPostCount($thread)` is just:
`$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM forum_posts WHERE threadid = '$thread'`

This is a problem because it has to do this for each thread and there are 20 threads per page.

Is there any other way I can get this information beforehand or somehow minimize the queries required to get this information? There are 150 users on at any given time so 3K queries per page load is not something I want.

Thanks.

Edit: the EXPLAIN of the query I was given to use:
[mysql explain http://screensnapr.com/e/01hulx.png](http://screensnapr.com/e/01hulx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use joins:

```
SELECT  t.*, COUNT(fp.id)
FROM    threads t
LEFT JOIN
        forum_posts fp
ON      fp.threadid = t.id
ORDER BY
        t.last_updated DESC
LIMIT 20
```

However, this still requires the engine to count posts for each thread on each reload.

You could enable query cache (it's ideal for the queries like that) or just add a `post_count` field to `threads` and update it each time a post is made or deleted.

Comment: I've tried this before, and doing a query like this basically kills MySQL and it takes forever to come back with a result. So, I don't know if it's something wrong with mysql or if the amount of posts is too large (300k posts, 34k threads)

Comment: I added appropriate relationships between the threads and post table and all went smoothly.

Comment: @Tar: Create an index on `forum_threads (boardid, sticky, lastbump)` and another one on `forum_posts (threadid)`.